# How to wrap every image in a post with a div?

Tags: posts, customization, html, images

When I add an image to a post I want it to be in a div e.g. , and I want that to be done automatically, so I don't have to do that in HTML editor.
I don't want to use js to accomplish this and by the way I want to know how to automatically add custom classes to a image in a post. Cheers!

Comment: Search for `image_send_to_editor`, that would be a good filter to look at for what you're asking, search and you'll find info(sorry not got enough spare time to prepare an answer for you right now).

Comment: Can I ask why you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default images already have unique class's but this depends on your theme. Use firebug and hover over the images and you should see stuff like `class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-1525"`.

If you want to change the class or id or alter any attributes of the image you can use the `get_image_tag` filter. For example,

```
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','my_custom_class');

function my_custom_class($class){
$class='my_custom_name';
return $class;
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for that but what if I want to wrap every single image with a div e.g. #imagecontainer so I can tweak the design the way I want?

Comment: Then you use the filter I put above.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following code while making some research. You can easily wrap a Post image in a Div by using the built-in filter of WordPress i.e **image_send_to_editor**. Here is an example,

```
if( is_admin() ) {

    add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wp_image_wrap_init', 10, 8 );  
    function wp_image_wrap_init( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
        return '<div id="wp-image-wrap-'. $id .'" class="wp-image-wrap">'. $html .'</div>';
    }

}
```

Thanks to http://wpalkane.com/hacks/wrap-post-image-inside-div-automatically/

Answer (score 1):

You answer was close but not enough because the hook checkpoint for get_image_tag_**class()** only changes the class attribute. So I was playing around and find out that the right thing for wrapping each image is **get_image_tag()** so the code goes like this :

```
function my_image_tag($html, $id , $alt, $title){

$html = "<div class='**wrap-div**'>" . $html . "</div>";
return $html;
}

add_filter('get_image_tag','my_image_tag',10,4);
```

You answer was partially right so it's the best one ;)
Cheers mate and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the answers here can be divided into 2 methods:

**1) functions, that work in POST EDITOR (back-end)** (see posted answers)
**2) functions, that work in POST OUTPUT (front-end)**

p.s. another methods to change front-end output:

a)

```
function my_image_class_filter($classes) {
    return $classes . ' another-image-class';
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', 'my_image_class_filter');
```

b)

```
function add_post_image_class($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<img(.*?)class="(.*?)"/', '<img $1 class="$2 YOUR_CLASS_NAME"', $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_post_image_class' );
```

Comment: This is no chat. Please use proper Upper/lower case letters and care a bit about code formatting. Later readers will come and vote on your answer and they also take readability in account. Thanks.